# How to fix "no lowerable accent" error in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, accents, linguistics, tipa

I'm writing a linguistic paper and have to use several IPA characters with certain accents (e.g. œ̞, ʉ̟). I thought I might use XeLaTeX. I have tried using the tipa-package, but I only get an error saying "no lowerable accent in position 27" and no accent is shown. Here is part of the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[margin=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[tone]{tipa}
\usepackage{vowel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\textipa[1]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\tipaencoding #1}}

\textipa{\|`\oe}, \textipa{\|+0}

\end{document}
```

In this code I have explicitly changed the font for the IPA characters to Computer Modern. Otherwise, no IPA character would be shown. This gives
[image]

Which obviously isn't as it is supposed to be (no accents).

I have also tried to use a font supporting IPA characters, but that font doesn't look good together with the font of XeLaTeX.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a font that supports the IPA characters, for instance CMU Serif:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\|`\oe}, \textipa{\|+0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also input the characters directly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\|`\oe}, \textipa{\|+0}

œ̞ ʉ̟

^^^^0153^^^^031e ^^^^0289^^^^031f

\end{document}
```

The third line is using the Unicode points.

[image]

Comment: @OskarEkestorm Sorry for being so late, but I didn't see your question.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm just glad that my question has been answered.